# Referring .mxml tag from (not included) actionscript file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a `Home.mxml` file with `home_src.as` included in a `fx:Script` tag. Now suppose that I want to retrieve the value of a `<mx:TextInput.../>` tag located in `Home.mxml`, from another .as file (for example `login_src.as`).

I tried `mx.core.Application.application.[file.mxml].[property]` but doesn't work (I obtain an error like this: *property  not found on* ).

I don't know if it is possible without including the .as file who wants access to the .mxml property, but I want to find out because I have a canvas.mxml page (with some text and combo tag) that contains a tabNavigator with two other .mxml pages; in the actionscript of these two tabs I need the value of canvas.mxml input and combo tag.

Is there a way to do this without including tab1 or tab2.as into my canvas.mxml?

A button click opens a popup for data insertion:

*home.as*

```
..
var insertPop:InsertPopUp = InsertPopUp(PopUpManager.createPopUp((this.parentApplication as DisplayObject), InsertPopUp, true));
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(insertPop);
..
```

*InsertPopUp.mxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="init()" close="close()">

<mx:Script source="InsertPopUp_src.as"/>

<mx:Label id="lblage" text="Age:"/>
<mx:TextInput id="txtAge" editable="true"/> // I want this data

<mx:TabNavigator id="insertTab" width="100%" height="85%">
        <mx:VBox id="vbx1" width="100%" height="100%"  label="Car Data">
            <mx:ModuleLoader id="mdlCatData" url="modules/Cat.swf" height="100%" width="100%" />
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:VBox id="vbx2" width="100%" height="100%" label="Van Data">
            <mx:ModuleLoader id="mdlDogData" url="modules/Dog.swf" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        </mx:VBox>
</mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Then I have:

*Cat.mxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="init();">

<mx:Script source="CatData_src.as" />

// other forms..

</mx:Module>
```

and:

*Dog.mxml*

```
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="init();">

<mx:Script source="DogData_src.as" />

// other forms..

</mx:Module>
```

I want to retrieve data of the `txtAge` textInput and use it in both *CatData_src.as* and *DogData_src.as*; how can I get that data without resorting to a script include?
I made this "graphic configuration" because some data are common to Cat and Dog.. (obviously is just an example).

Comment: Post some code. In general, if you give you MXML tags an id, it will be a public property on the MXML component and you access it that way.

Comment: From InsertPopUp_src.as you can access your data directly using txtAge just like a normal variable access. But this variable is only pointing to a valid object when the components are created like in the creationComplete event for example.

Comment: Yes I know that from InsertPopUp_src.as I can access txtAge normally.. The two tab are inside the InsertPopUp.mxml then when I open this, both two tab (or surely the first one) is immediateli initialized.. come on guys I can't do a more simple example.. For example I can't write a getter in InsertPopUp_src.as and call this method in Cat_src.as/Dog_src.as?? I waiting a response since 10 hours, reading this is a little bit frustrating..

Comment: @junior_developer There's no guarantee of an instant answer on Stack Overflow...remember, you're asking *random strangers on the internet* for help.  Similarly, the idea here is basically "the programming FAQ of the Internet" - I edited your question a bit with that in mind.

Comment: ...Also, have you read the docs on [passing data to modules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64277-7fea.html)?  I'm not sure if you can rely on the query-string technique or if you'll need to access the parent application from your modules.  Do you only need that `txtAge` data when you load your modules, or do you need to see any changes after they're already running?

Comment: You are right Brian.. sorry to you and to everybody. I was anxiously waiting for an answer because I thought that this kind of data access was possible.. The _txtAge_ component is just an example, I need many others data (but are all txtInput or combobox ) from the module. This is a big form for inserting data, composed with 3 modules but the SAVE button is just one (obviously) and is on the third module. When I save data I need even the data (textInput contents and combobox selected values) if others two modules.. I really can't believe that there isn't a way do this. Thanks and sorry guys

Comment: Yes Brian I have read the passing data to modules doc you have post.. But with the method parentApplication I can't reach the parent of my modules.. but the root of my application.. the first .mxml with tag Application.. I don't know... I posted the same question on the Adobe forum but noone respond.. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

mxml is not anything special in the world of AS3, it seems different but it's really not as it is compiled later into AS3 code. Any object declared in mxml tag with an id is just a property of the as3 class that will be generated (using the same name as the mxml file).

If that mxml class is supposed to be unique (not 2 instances of it) you can access your property using static methods.

Example:

- mxml main class named: MyMain.mxml
- declare static variable (in fx:script) of type MyMain: static public var instance:MyMain;
- in addedToStage listener (or similar) set your variable: instance = this
- from anywhere access your instance and property: MyMain.instance.mytextimput

If working with multiple instances of mxml class then get reference of the instance and use it just like any other AS3 object.

Comment: Can you have a look to the code I posted? I don't know if editing my first question is the way to respond to your answer... maybe I had to put the code in this comment??